# Rpeat Process In Php With Restrictions

Tags: php, sql

I want to make Bulk Sms Service.

I Have an Api in which we have to provide the Recipient Numbers As 92312xxxxx

```
 ETC 12 Numeric Characters
```

I want to make bulk SMS Service and be able to Send it in one click like :

```
Recipient Parameters
92312xxxxxxx,92323xxxxxxx,923xxxxxxxxx, .......... up to End
```

I Have Searched Deeply But Totally Puzzled How to Do it ??

Further Recipient Numbers Have Some Restrictions Too That Are Parameters

```
Restrictions

Parameter Error 1 = RECIPIENT Can't be Greater than 12 or Less Than 12

Parameter Error 2 = Recipient First Third Characters Are 923
```

If And Any Error Occurs :

***Skip the Wrong Number And GO to Next Recipient

 *Decrease A Column One BY one (Balance) side by side From SQL table**

IF During Process Sql Column value Reached On Zero Then Stop The Whole Process and Echo : **You have used Your Credit**

```
<?php
$mysender2 = "Not Use";
$myrecepient2 = "923126812536";
$msg = "The Message That Will Go Again Again In Curl Untill Process Complete 

or SQL Column Reached Zero";

$url = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?" .
         "api_key=".$api_key. "&" .
         "api_secret="  .$api_secret . "&" .
         "from="  . urlencode($mysender2) . "&" .
         "to=" . urlencode($myrecepient2) . "&" .
         "text=" .urlencode($msg);


$c = curl_init($url); 

// Use SSL 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$html = curl_exec($c); 
?>
```

Comment: WhY Do YoU tYpE LiEK THis?

Comment: @MurifoX i ThouGht everYBody DID thaT.

Comment: @MurifoX Its not nice to make fun of people who have StuTtering leFt piNky fIngEr hitTinG Caps loCk disoRder.